# tooltip which brings external page in it

Tags: javascript, tooltip

i m looking for a tooltip which can dispaly external php page in to it and which can adjust itself up and down with respext to screen size,can some one suggest me jquery or javascript code.It should work on ajax page also.if i delete something by using ajax then tooltip should appear on ajax

Comment: possible duplicate of [tooltip in browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365948/tooltip-in-browser)

Answer (score 1):

try this on [tiptip](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin) the bet one you can load image in this

[TipTip jQuery Plugin](http://vimeo.com/8508658) from [Valio, Inc.](http://vimeo.com/valioinc) on [Vimeo](http://vimeo.com).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [jquery.cluetip](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/#)
look at basic ajax,

Answer (score 0):

refer [40+ Tooltips Scripts With AJAX, JavaScript & CSS][1]

[1]: to http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/06/12/tooltips-scripts-ajax-javascript-css-dhtml/

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you want to show and external website, or use something like AJAX to display a single PHP file's output. As for the popup, there is [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/), or you could write your own. To make the popup relative to the screen, you will have to get the width and height of the window, which can be a little hard in different browsers. jQuery, however, makes things much easier:

```
$(window).width();
$(window).height();
```

If you want the *document* dimensions, replace `$(window)` with `$(document)`

To fetch a PHP file and display it's output in a `div` (for example), I'd use jQuery's `$.get()`. An example is shown below:

```
$.get('path/to/php.php', function(data) {
  $('#popup_div).html(data);
});
```

Hope this helps,

James